# Whenever I run "apt-get install php5-gd php-mysql" it states "Unable to locate package php-mysql" on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, php, mysql, oracle, ubuntu

I am trying to run the command

```
apt-get install php5-gd php-mysql
```

but whenever I run the command it states this:

```
E: Unable to locate package php-mysql
```

My Dedicated Server is running Ubuntu 14.04, it is hosted by So You Start.

The thing is, it was working before, along with java, and mysql, and php.
Is it possible that this is just a side effect of a bigger problem that needs to be fixed? When I try to install java, this shows up:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
openjdk-7-jre-headless is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer                        required:
libdbi-perl libterm-readkey-perl mysql-client-core-5.5
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u121-1~webupd8~0) ...
Installing from local file /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/jdk-8u121-linux-           x64.tar.gz
Removing outdated cached downloads...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin/ControlPanel     to provide /usr/bin/ControlPanel (ControlPanel) in auto mode
update-alternatives: error: error creating symbolic link     `/etc/alternatives/ControlPanel.dpkg-tmp': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-    up error from a previous failure.
                        dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-    installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of oracle-java8-set-default:
 oracle-java8-set-default depends on oracle-java8-installer; however:
  Package oracle-java8-installer is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-set-default (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
 oracle-java8-set-default
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php5-mysql`

Comment: Returns this:                                                                                 Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package php5-mysql is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'php5-mysql' has no installation candidate

Comment: Try replacing `php5` with `php` - I think latest Ubuntu is on PHP 7 now, so the `5` component would/should have been removed.

Comment: or try php5.6-gd etc

Comment: Now it says no installation candidate

Comment: Update your apt package info, then search for your package, before installation.

Comment: `apt-cache search php | grep mysql` and install the correct one for your system.

Answer (score 0):

I'm on 14.04, and `php5-mysql` is fine:

```
$ apt-cache search php5-mysql
php5-mysql - MySQL module for php5
php5-mysqlnd - MySQL module for php5 (Native Driver)
php5-mysqlnd-ms - MySQL replication and load balancing module for PHP
```

Try doing an update first before doing the install:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php5-mysql
```